# Что лучше использовать? (Глобальная переменная VS Создание нового экземпляра класса)

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Вопрос в том, какой из указанных случаев лучше (Первый случай и второй соответственно).
*Лучше в плане скорости работы, ресурсопотребления и практичности использования.*

**Файл foo.php**

```
require_once(__DIR__ . 'SameClass.php'); // Подключаем класс
$sameclass = new SameClass(); // Инициализируем его
$sameclass->init(); // Вызываем любой метод

require_once(__DIR__ . 'bar.php'); // Подключаем второй файл
```

**Файл bar.php**

```
/* Инициализируем с помощью ранее объявленной переменной (#1 Случай) */
function sameFunction1() {
    global $sameclass; // Глобальная переменная
    return $sameclass->samemethod(); // Возвращаем метод класса
}

/* Создаём экземпляр класса в функции и снова инициализируем (#2 Случай) */
function sameFunction2() {
    require_once(__DIR__ . 'SameClass.php'); // Подключаем класс
    $sameclass = new SameClass(); // Инициализируем его
    return $sameclass->samemethod(); // Возвращаем метод класса
}
```

Comment: Что первое - шлак, что что второе.... В 2022 пора бы на autoload перейти

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну это пример с загрузкой класса через require, сути это не меняет

Comment: Окей. Если выбор между двумя шлаками - тогда можно брать любой..... Важно в первую очередь чтобы другим было понятно что происходит и меньше магии, а скорость достигается другими способами, а не сферической в вакууме

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, вопрос, как сделать правильно?

Comment: В самом первом комментарии написано...... + можно использовать для этих целей composer + autoload psr-4

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну плюс первого шлака в том, что мы не создаём новый объект, что может быть полезно в случае если мы что то поменяли в классе. во втором случае мы создаём начисто объект и поэтому конфигурировать класс придется заново. для меня это самая очевидная разница

Comment: Как скажете. Вам предстоит ещё очень большой путь пройти, скажу я вам))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в первом комментарии ничего кроме автоматической загрузки классов несказанно.

Comment: p.s у меня в проекте и так все через composer autoload и psr-4 сделано

Comment: Тогда зачем вопрос про эти два недоподхода - не ясно

Comment: Это как закупиться лучшим современным оборудованием для лечения пациентов, но всё равно использовать подорожник и заговоры..

Comment: так есть же bootstrap файл, в котором куча последовательного  кода. соответственно есть некая библиотека например, которая используется в этом файле, но помимо этого файла есть ещё функция которая что то там делает и для её работы нужна эта библиотека. так вот, как лучше, использовать хвост с bootstrap.php через глобалку или заново инициализировать класс в функции.

Comment: Да собственно глобалки считаются плохой практикой.

Comment: а где вариант с `somefunction3($obj){ return $obj->method(); }`